# WeakEventManager - event handler is not called

Tags: c#, event-handling, weak-events, weakeventmanager

I am not able to reproduce the issue (and project is too big to post it here, plus I am not sure what are related parts to post) and I need ideas of what *could* go wrong here.

I have abstract class with static event

```
public abstract partial class A : Base
{
    public static event EventHandler Test;
    public static void OnTest() => Test?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Then I subscribe to this event normally and using `WeakEventManager`:

```
A.Test += (s, e) => { };
WeakEventManager<A, EventArgs>.AddHandler(null, nameof(A.Test), (s, e) => { });
```

And for *some reasons* weak event handler doesn't get fired when `OnTest()` is called. Everything (invoke and handlers) are operating in the UI thread.

I've set breakpoints:

1. On `AddHandler()`, it runs and the instance of class then persist.
2. On `Invoke()`, it runs when `OnTest` is called, I can see 2 subscribers if I call `Test.GetInvocationList()` one of them is `DeliverEvent()` from `WeakEventManager`, so event was registered and `Invoke()` should call weak event handler.
3. Inside normal event handler, it runs.
4. Inside weak event handler, **nothing**, this breakpoint never get hit.

Any ideas of why would this occur or what should I investigate?

---

I've tried to look into .net [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/WeakEventManagerT.cs,a795c952f2e86713), to find answers there, but there is `ProtectedAddHandler` which sources I can't find...
I found [it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/WeakEventManager.cs,8342114dd19d0988), but what is the next? Abstract method, who implements it?...

Comment: What abstract method are you talking about? ProtectedAddHandler and AddHandler are both not abstract

Comment: To debug the issue, I would add a finalizer to the subscriber class which will output a debug message to inform when it was finalized.

Answer (score 0):

> `WeakEventManager` ... not working event handler ...

To whoever face this issue, the problem is this: **you must rise `static` event with `null` as `sender`**! E.g. in my case it was (use this to reproduce issue with code in the question):

```
public static void OnTest() => Test?.Invoke("whatever", EventArgs.Empty);
```

This case will be handled by **normal** subscriber without any problem.

But in case of `WeakEventManager` it must be a `null` (special case), otherwise your  event handler will not work.

---